# Test Create EmailMessage for Case

Tags: apex, unit-test

I need to insert a Case with an EmailMessage. My first test looks like this and it passes when no email is associated to an Case.

```
public static Case setupCase(){
    Case newCase = (Case)SmartFactory.CreateSObject('Case');
    newCase.EmailMessage.FromAddress = '';
    insert newCase;
    return newCase;
}

public static void setupEmailMessage(){
    EmailMessage newEmail = (EmailMessage)SmartFactory.CreateSObject('EmailMessage');
    newEmail.FromAddress='test@email.com';
    insert newEmail;
}

@isTest static void testEmailNotPopulated() {
    Case newCase = setupCase();
    setupEmailMessage(newCase);
    System.assertEquals([Select Email_From__c from Case where Id=:newCase.Id].Email_From__c, null);
}
```

The problem is I only attach the EmailMessage after I have inserted the Case. How can I insert a Case with the EmailMessage associated?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you are trying to do, but my understanding is the relationship between Case and EmailMessage is handled by the EmailMessage.ParentId field. You could set the EmailMessage.ParentId field to the Case.Id before inserting it.

Comment: Forgot to add my trigger is a before case insert so I need to add the EmailMessage with a ParentId of the Case before I insert the Case. Is that possible?

Comment: The Case won't have an ID until after it is inserted. In an after insert trigger on the case you could find a related EmailMessage and update the ParentId then.